# P2P payments with PayPal on mobile devices

Tags: mobile, paypal

I'm looking into supporting P2P payments for a mobile app, iOS as well as Android. I do not think the PayPal API has support for this, what would be the best way to achieve this?

I need a verification preferably of a payment made to another user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PayPal absolutely supports this.  You have a number of options.  You can use their actual [mobile SDK's](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/mobile-sdk-overview/) or you can just build standard HTTP requests to the API end-point like usual.

When using Express Checkout or Adaptive Payments their system will automatically switch to using the mobile checkout experience when a mobile device is used.  This way you can build your apps to run on mobile devices or regular computers (with jQuery Mobile, for example) and it would give the user the experience they expect.

Comment: Link is broken. Can you check it out.

Comment: Yeah, they moved everything.  It's fixed.

Comment: Can you tell where is the documentation that states that P2P is possible in PayPal.I am not able to find that.

Comment: The best way would be the [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) platform.  Specifically, the [Pay API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/).